# Eclipse reports rendering library more recent than ADT plug-in update Provisioning Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

On a new Android SDK installation, the Eclipse Graphical Layout is blank, rather than showing the rendering the layout. Eclipse displays this message:

> This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in

This bug report lists the steps to reproduce. I followed below this steps, to clear the bug

```
1. Click Help >Install New Software.
2. In the Work with field, enter: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. Select Developer Tools / Android Development Tools.
4. Click Next and complete the wizard.
```

But next thing, Provisioning Error:

```
    eclipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759
    java.version=1.7.0_25
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

    Error
    Mon Sep 23 15:52:03 IST 2013
    Provisioning exception

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: No repository found at file:/D:/Android-Software/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **Help** > **Install New Software**
2. In the **Work with** field, enter : `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
3. Select **Developer Tools**
4. Click **Next** and complete the wizard.

Ref : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60180#hc17