# How to correct "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update"?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I have recently installed Eclipse Neon, the Android SDK, and everything that is required.  However, I can't view the graphic layout.  I have done all the following suggested, but none has worked.

1. I went into the SDK manager, clicked on the latest API (24) and installed. (nothing)
2. I went to Help>Check Updates.  It informed me all updates are installed.
3. I went to Help > Install new software.  I put in the website for developer tools and installed the developer tools packet.  After that I reboot the system and still the error shows up.

I do notice that when I start Eclipse, it loads SDK contents Android 6.0 and Android 7.0.

I don't know what else to do?

Comment: Several more [possible duplicates here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=This+version+of+the+rendering+library+is+more+recent+than+your+version+of+ADT+plug-in.+Please+update).

Comment: Another possible dup: [Eclipse reports rendering library more recent than ADT plug-in update Provisioning Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957303/eclipse-reports-rendering-library-more-recent-than-adt-plug-in-update-provisioni).

Comment: Easy solution: switch to Andros Studio.